# Что не так с Split функцией?

Tags: c#, функции, vb.net, split

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в данном случае x.Split("#*#")неправильно разбивает строку в массив и что с этим можно поделать

```
  For Each i As String In massiv_zakaz 'Начинаем работу с каждым товаром заказа
        

Dim elements() As String = Split(i, "#*#") 'Разбиваем элемент на составляющие в массив

Dim element_baza() As String = Split(massiv_baza.Find(Function(x)
                                                                     Dim mass As String() = x.Split("#*#")
                                                                      If mass(1) = elements(0) Then Return True Else Return False 'Ищем в базе поставщиков по Штрихкоду и артикулы поставщиков
                                                                  End Function), "#*#")
```

пример элемента в massiv_baza, который разбивается Сплитом (разделителем является такая последовательность: "#*#"):

```
"1f368002-851a-11e9-9ff4-315000584a8d#*#2000000018751#*#Мотозапчасти/Аккумуляторы"
```

Результат как он разбивает строку в mass ( звёздочка через каждый элемент почему-то):

[image: скришот1]

На 2м скриншоте как он разбивает правильно в elements() совершенно аналогичную строку с таким же разделителем:

[image: скриншот2]

Comment: *Результат как он разбивает строку в mass ( звёздочка через каждый элемент почему-то):* Вы проверьте описание функции. Такое впечатление, что в качестве разделителя используется только первый символ переданной подстроки..

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split Строка в качестве разделителя работает только если делить надо массив строк. См. последний пример.

Comment: Либо разделитель воспринимается как регулярное выражение. Но в документации такого нигде не написано :/

Comment: спасибо, проблему удалось понять

Answer (score 2):

Оказывается, `Split(i, "#*#")` и `x.Split("#*#")` - это разные функции, разных версий `vb`.

`x.Split()` - вызывается перегрузка принимающая массив `Char`. Чтобы передать строку придется сделать так: `x.Split({"#*#"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`. Поэтому, в моем случае он разделял только по первому символу.

Либо можно просто использовать везде старую функцию `Split(i, "#*#")`, что я и сделал.